# Ubuntu 21.10 - GDM problem - login screen

Tags: login-screen, gdm, 21.10

I just upgrade my desktop from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10.  Everything works fine! I was happy.

But after that, I run a wrong program that will change the background of the graphical login screen to another picture.

Mostly likely the Script that I run:
I downloaded the following program during 21.04 and install and run it.

```
 github.com/thiggy01/gdm-background

 gdm-background/gdm-background-helper /


#!/usr/bin/env python3

import distro
import dbus
import dbus.service
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from gi.repository import GLib
import shutil
from subprocess import call

class GDMBackground(dbus.service.Object):

    if distro.id() == 'ubuntu':
        default_theme = '/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource'
    elif distro.id() == 'pop':        
        default_theme = '/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Pop/gnome-shell-theme.gresource'
    
    backup_theme = default_theme + '~'

    def __init__(self, conn=None, object_path=None, bus_name=None):
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, conn, object_path, bus_name)

    @dbus.service.method('xyz.thiggy01.GDMBackground', in_signature='s', out_signature='b',
        sender_keyword='sender', connection_keyword='conn')
    def SetImage(self, task, sender=None, conn=None):
        action_id = 'xyz.thiggy01.GDMBackground.SetImage'
        if self._check_polkit_privilege(sender, conn, action_id):
            if task == 'backup':
                shutil.copy(self.default_theme, self.backup_theme)
            elif task == 'set':
                shutil.move("/tmp/gdm3/theme/gnome-shell-theme.gresource", self.default_theme)
                return True
        else:
            return False

    @dbus.service.method('xyz.thiggy01.GDMBackground', in_signature='s', out_signature='b',
        sender_keyword='sender', connection_keyword='conn')
    def RestoreBackup(self, task, sender=None, conn=None):
        action_id = 'xyz.thiggy01.GDMBackground.RestoreBackup'
        if self._check_polkit_privilege(sender, conn, action_id):
            if task == 'restore':
                shutil.move(self.backup_theme, self.default_theme)
                return True
        else:
            return False

    @dbus.service.method('xyz.thiggy01.GDMBackground', in_signature='s', out_signature='',
        sender_keyword='sender', connection_keyword='conn')
    def RestartGDM(self, action_id, sender=None, conn=None):
            if self._check_polkit_privilege(sender, conn, action_id):
                call(['/usr/sbin/service', 'gdm', 'restart'])

    def _check_polkit_privilege(self, sender, conn, action_id):
        if sender is None and conn is None:
            return

        self.proxy_dbus = dbus.Interface(conn.get_object('org.freedesktop.DBus',
            '/org/freedesktop/DBus/Bus', False), 'org.freedesktop.DBus')
        sender_pid = self.proxy_dbus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID(sender)

        self.proxy_polkit = dbus.Interface(dbus.SystemBus().get_object(
            'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1', '/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority', False),
            'org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority')

        try:
            (is_auth, is_challenge, details) = self.proxy_polkit.CheckAuthorization(
                ('unix-process', {'pid': dbus.UInt32(sender_pid, variant_level=1),
                                  'start-time': dbus.UInt64(0, variant_level=1)}),
                 action_id, {'':''}, dbus.UInt32(1), 'cancel')
            if is_auth:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except dbus.DBusException as error:
            self.proxy_polkit.CancelCheckAuthorization('cancel')
            raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
   
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    name = dbus.service.BusName('xyz.thiggy01.GDMBackground', bus)
    gdm_background_helper = GDMBackground(name, '/xyz/thiggy01/GDMBackground')
    GLib.MainLoop().run()
```

After that the Ubuntu 21.10 cannot load the graphical login screen anymore.

There is an error on the screen: Monitor SAD face with the message "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator.

I try troubleshoot the problem by running Ubuntu 21.10 using recovery mode. Then go to the root and using the commands:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
systemctl status gdm
systemctl start gdm
```

It doesn't work at all.

I suspect the program / script I run has conflict the set up of GNOME 40 with Ubuntu 21.04. Please help me to get back the original GUI login screen setting.

I try to login to Ubuntu 21.04 using CTRL-SHIFT-F3.  Then I type:

```
systemctl status gdm3

gdm.service is active (running)
Starting GNOME Display Manager.....
```

But there is an error message:

```
Gdm:  GdmDisplay:  Session never registered, failing
Gdm: Child process -2037 was already dead.
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the name of the program or the contents of the script that you ran to change the background of the login screen? This may help someone offer a specific solution to your problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and put the info there, not in the comments.

Comment: I just did, thanks!

Comment: I end up uninstall gnome session, gnome desktop and gdm3 so that I can get back to sddm login - using KDE and XFCE.  As soon as I install GNOME again, the problem persists.  Please suggest for a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. First you'll need to get to a recovery root console. Pressing left shift or escape during boot should do it. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

### What might be sufficient

I installed lightdm, but I'm not sure if installing lightdm and switching back to gdm3 was required. This might work:

```
sudo apt reinstall gdm3 gnome-shell yaru-theme-gnome-shell
sudo service gdm3 restart
```

### What I did

First I ran the restore option to put the original file back. No effect. I used a different script with a --restore flag, not the Python code you posted. It looks like both of them just do this:

```
mv /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource~ \
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

Then I installed lightdm.

```
# Should install then show UI to switch from gdm3 to lightdm
sudo apt install lightdm
```

Rebooted and that worked, but UI was glitchy once I logged back into Gnome. For example: hitting the Super key brought up the app search box, but icons were drawn overlapping and flickering like a framebuffer issue. Also lightdm showed Ubuntu version 21.04 in the bottom left corner. I don't think lightdm + gnome is properly supported in 21.10 yet.

Finally, I reinstalled gdm3, gnome-shell, and the yaru theme and switched from lightdm back to gdm.

```
sudo apt reinstall gdm3 gnome-shell yaru-theme-gnome-shell
# Switch back to gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Rebooted and everything works again, still the same default background image for gdm3. It is beyond tedious that it requires hacking to change a background image, but here we are.

Comment: Thanks Caller9.  Give thanks! Your solution works, I reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop, along with gdm3 gnome-shell yaru-theme-gnome-shell.  Now I can login to GNOME40 under GDM!  Great stuff..  much appreciated!